# Image zooming out in Firefox. Need to click on it to get actual size

Tags: php, html, image, iframe

I'm trying to display an image within an iFrame on my page. The problem I face is that in Firefox, the image seems to be zoomed out automatically. I need to click on it to get the actual size. I know there is a manual fix for this by doing the following:

```
Enter about:config in Firefox address bar.
Look for browser.enable_automatic_image_resizing 
Change the value to false
```

I was wondering though if there was something I could write on my script that would automatically take care of it?

Comment: Merlin, I don't want my large image to introduce scroll bars to my page. Not the best way of doing it maybe, I know ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a div to get the same result as an iframe but without the resizing:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>foo</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style='overflow: scroll; width: 300px; height: 300px;'><img src="image.png" /></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Merlin, I tried this ... however, the scrollbars for the image are greyed out and I have scroll bars on my main page instead.

Comment: Merlin, it worked. I was setting the width, the same size as the image. That's why it was making it as big as the page. When I confined it to a fixed width, it did add the scroll bars. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you set the image as a background image it should stop FF from scaling it.

Comment: The image is a background for my iFrame. I've used an iFrame, since I don't want to add scrollbars to my page. I just want to add it to the iFrame.

echo"<iframe height='300' width='100%'></iframe>";

Comment: If the image truely is a background, i.e. not included using <img ... />, then it won't resize automatically.

Comment: jezmk ...sorry, I meant to say echo"<iframe height='300' width='100%' src=$image></iframe>, I do have it as a source for the iFrame but not the main background for the page ..